# User Online Status not updating automatically

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a working firebase chat app with online/offline status, all i want to figure is how to get this data without reloading table view. 
When the user goes offline i have to refresh my view to notice the changes.

Also how to change the navigation subtitle view without reloading view

My user Online and Offline method

```
func userOnline(UserId: String){
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let myConnectionRef = 
 Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(UserId)
    myConnectionRef.child("online").setValue(true)
   myConnectionRef.child("last_online").setValue(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
    myConnectionRef.child("last_online").setValue(NSNumber(value: Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)))

}

func userOffline(UserId: String){
    let myConnectionRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(UserId)
    myConnectionRef.child("online").setValue(false)
    myConnectionRef.child("last_online").setValue(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)

    myConnectionRef.child("last_online").setValue(NSNumber(value: Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)))

}


func checkUserStatus(userid:String){
    let myConnectionRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userid)
    myConnectionRef.child("online").setValue(true)
    myConnectionRef.child("typing").setValue(false)

    myConnectionRef.child("last_online").setValue(NSNumber(value: Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)))

    // Observe For User logged in or logged out
    myConnectionRef.observe(.childChanged) { (snapshot) in
        guard let connected = snapshot.value as? Bool, connected else {return}
    }
}
```

And I use if else statement to get change the cell.detailtext

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! UserCell
    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = user.userName
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    if (user.online as? Bool)!{
        cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.flatGreen()
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "online"
    }
    else {
         let date = user.last_online!
         let seconds = user.last_online?.doubleValue
         let timeStamp = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: seconds!)
         let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
         dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, d MMM yy hh:mm:a"
         cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
         cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
         cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ("Last Seen: \(dateFormatter.string(from: timeStamp as Date))")
    }



    if let profileImageUrl = user.profileImageUrl {
        cell.profileImageView.loadImageFromCache(urlString: profileImageUrl)

    }
    return cell
}
```

But i have to refresh the tableview.
is there a method to have this changes automatically

Comment: Can you post the full `cellForRow` code?

Comment: Yeah i have updated my `cellForRow`

Comment: Okay, as far as I understood you need to change the status of a user in another user's device whenever the online status changes for that particular user, without reloading the whole tableview. You can try using push notifications(silent preferred, but remote can also be done) whenever the user status changes.

Comment: can you tell me how to do it ?

Comment: Okay, give me some time, long code, will post as an answer.

Comment: I think you're looking to observe `.value` instead of `.childChanged`: `myConnectionRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in`.

Comment: In my database the value changes in real time and so do in my app, its just i have to reload the table view so that the text view will update which will show the new changed value is there a way to show a value which do not need any update of the table view

Answer (score 0):

You have to  store your data if you want to used in offline.

```
  Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
```

Also Keep sync your data

```
    let scoresRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "scores")
scoresRef.keepSynced(true)
```

for getting offline Data used

```
    let scoresRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "scores")
scoresRef.queryOrderedByValue().queryLimited(toLast: 4).observe(.childAdded) { snapshot in
  print("The \(snapshot.key) dinosaur's score is \(snapshot.value ?? "null")")
}
```

for more info refer [Firebase offline capability](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities)

Comment: Ohh you have got me wrong, I can store my database offline. This is about the user being online or offline. I want to let other user know which user is online

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Firebase has a simply superb [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) which enables to play with the database changes like sending push notifications. You can check the docs, go through it and setup a `node.js` platform for writing functions.

After the setup, following code is written for sending push notifications in the `index.js` file:

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

const tokens = [data.token];

const payload = {
          notification: {
            title: data.title,
            body: data.text,
          },
          data: data.data

        };
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then(() => {

  // Returning the sanitized message to the client.

       });
});
```

Okay, now you are ready with the sending part. Now the other user will receives it.

So, in the `AppDelegate`:

```
// This method will be called when app received push notifications in foreground
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("received push notification whilst in the foreground")

        let msg = notification.request.content

        if let group = msg.userInfo["chat"] as? String {
                let showingVC = UIApplication.topViewController()
                if showingVC is GroupChatVC {

                //here you will get the online status so update the status label by using the NSNotificationCenter
                    return // hide notification
                }

        }

        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert)
    }
```

In the `ViewController` where `userOnline()` and `userOffline()` are written:

```
    static var functions = Functions.functions()

func userOnline(UserId: String){
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let myConnectionRef = 
 Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(UserId)
    myConnectionRef.child("online").setValue(true)
   myConnectionRef.child("last_online").setValue(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
    myConnectionRef.child("last_online").setValue(NSNumber(value: Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)))
    self.send(toUserID: receiverUserID, title: Chat Status, text: msg, data: ["chat": "online"])

}

func userOffline(UserId: String){
    let myConnectionRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(UserId)
    myConnectionRef.child("online").setValue(false)
    myConnectionRef.child("last_online").setValue(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)

    myConnectionRef.child("last_online").setValue(NSNumber(value: Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)))
    self.send(toUserID: receiverUserID, title: Chat Status, text: msg, data: ["chat": "offline"])

}

static func send(toUserID: String, title:String, text: String, data: [String: Any]? = nil) {

        var value = Dictionary<String, Any>()
        value["type"] = "notification"
        value["to"] = toUserID
        value["text"] = text
        value["title"] = title
        if data != nil { value["data"] = data }
        Database.database().reference().ref("users/\(toUserID)/private/fcm").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (namesnapshot) in
            if namesnapshot.exists() {
                let token = namesnapshot.value as! String
                print("FOUND \(token)")
                value["token"] = token
                functions.httpsCallable("sendNotification").call(value) { (result, error) in

                    if let text = (result?.data as? [String: Any])?["text"] as? String {
                        print("Result \(text)")
                    }
                }
            }
        })

    }
```

Hope you know about the `FCM` and `NSNotificationCenter` parts. You can find those tutorials everywhere.

Comment: This is some serious coding, I do not know node.js ill figure it out thank you for reply. Ill let you know how it goes

Comment: I too was not aware of it before using Cloud Functions, the docs is simple and easily understandable

Comment: ok Ill give it a try btw this my first project still a learner in swift